# jQuery Live Form Validation in Wordpress

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

I'm trying to implement the form validation that can be found at: http://www.geektantra.com/2009/09/jquery-live-form-validation/

I can get the demo above working, but when I implement it on my wordpress site no validation occurs.

The page where it's implemented is here: http://www.melbournemeditationcentre.com/meditation-courses/course-registration/

You'll see that the neccesary scripts are included:

1. jquery.validate.js?ver=3.8
2. jquery.js?ver=1.10.2
3. form-validation.css?ver=3.8

as well as the necessary code in the head:

```
jQuery(function(){
        jQuery("#firstname").validate({
            expression: "if (VAL.match(/^[A-Za-z '-]{3,20}$/) && VAL) return true; else return false;",
            message: "Required."
        });
    });
```

etc....

As far as I can tell, the form itself is all okay. Still no validation.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your page through javascript errors. Try loading the validation scripts on footer (before closing `</body>` tag) rather than within header (within `<head>` tag).

If that doesn't work, then try editing the `jquery.validate.js` file, and replace the first line `(function(jQuery){` with `(function($){`. It should work.

Comment: Moving the scripts to the footer worked. I didn't need to change the first line in jquery.validate.js

Comment: This answer ignores all the functionality WordPress offers you to declare dependencies and script locations.